Cakephp 5 Form Helper ¿Cómo mostrar errores de validacion antes de enviar un formulario?
Estoy haciendo el tutorial cms de cakephp 5 con la validación de formularios de Boostrap 5.
Al momento de querer enviar el formulario para probar la validación de los inputs, puedo ver que el HTML generado por el Form Helper no muestra el div class "invalid-feedback" que es el div y la clase que le puse en el Form Helper, inspeccionando los elementos con la herramienta del navegador, el div que contiene el mensaje de error no aparece en la estructura html del elemento, solo se muestra el div con el mensaje de error cuando el formulario ya fue validado y me redirecciona a la vista del formulario nuevamente, he intentado modificar el Form Helper para que se muestre un div personalizado con el error que quiero mostrar y si se genera el HTML con el div, pero no muestra el texto con el error que quiero mostrar, sale el div vacío sin el mensaje de error.
Imagen antes de enviar el formulario

Imagen después de enviar el formulario, donde si se muestra el mensaje de error.

Por default el Form Helper genera un div class="error-message" para los inputs required, yo le cambie la clase al div por este:
/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php
'error' => '<div id="{{id}}" class="invalid-feedback">{{content}}</div>'

En la variable inputContainer tiene lo siguiente:
'inputContainer' => '<div class="input {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}</div>'

Intenté agregar {{error}} después de {{content}} en inputContainer pero el div invalid-feedback sigue sin generarse, solo se genera si lo pongo directamente en lugar de {{error}} de esta forma, pero el mensaje de error que quiero mostrar no se muestra:
'inputContainer' => '<div class="input {{type}}{{required}}">{{content}}<div class="invalid-feedback">{{error}}</div></div>'

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto posible, mostrar el div con el mensaje de error antes de enviar el formulario?
La validación de boostrap 5 la quiero para mostrar posibles errores en el llenado del formulario antes de ser enviado.
Espero y puedan ayudarme por favor.

Es PHP,serverside,tienes que enviar el formulario para poder hacer la validación de la entidad en el servidor. Si quieres mostrar los errores sin recargar la página del formulario tendrías que usar ajax y pintar con js todo. Pero no puedes querer que se muestren los mensajes de error sin enviar los datos. Igualmente por ajax necesitarías eventos del usuario, por lo que tendrías que usar el botón de enviar aunque no haga el submit como tal si no por ajax.

En StackOverflow reservamos el espacio de respuestas para aportes que de alguna forma buscan brindar una solución concreta al problema planteado en la pregunta. A veces la pregunta no es lo suficientemente clara o nuestros consejos no son lo suficientemente concretos. Para estos casos, usamos la sección de comentarios, ya sea para dejar alguna recomendación o para pedir aclaraciones sobre la respuesta. Te invito a leer [answer].

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Gracias @Alberto Suárez Pérez
